# Factor group versus factor ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My text states:

> The homomorphism $\phi$ of the group $\langle R,+\rangle $ gives rise to a factor group (i.e. quotient group). Similarly, we expect that a ring homomorphism will give rise to a factor ring.

Can someone give me two simple examples? One on factor group and another on factor ring? Thanks so much!

Comment: You're gonna have to be a little bit specific about what $\phi$ is.

Comment: What is your text?

Comment: @MathDamon: Looking through your participation here, it seems that you've **never** posted a single comment in response to people asking you for clarification of your questions. That makes me, and I think many others, extremely disinterested in helping you. You need to provide enough information so that people can make sense of your questions, and respond to people when they ask for more information. So, for now, I am downvoting this post.